# Can I use regex capturing groups in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2014, capturing-group

I have some text data in an SQL Server 2014 table in which I want to detect complex patterns and extract certain portions of the text if the text matches the pattern. Because of this, I need capturing groups.

**E.g.**
From the text

```
"Some title, Some Journal name, vol. 5, p. 20-22"
```

I want to grab the volume number

```
, vol\. ([0-9]+), p\. [0-9]+
```

Mind that I have simplified this use-case to improve readability. The above use-case *could* be solved without capturing groups. The actual use-case handles a lot more exceptions, like:

- The journal/title containing "vol.".
- Volume numbers/pages containing letters
- "vol" being followed by ":" or ";" instead of "."
- ...

The actual regex I use is the following (yet, this is not a question on regex structure, just elaborating on why I need capturing groups).

```
(^|§|[^a-z0-9])vol[^a-z0-9]*([a-z]?[0-9]+[a-z]?)
```

As far as I know, there are two ways of getting Regex functionality into SQL Server.

- Through CLR: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/ . Yet, this example (from 2009) does not support groups. Are there any commonly used solutions out there that do?
- By installing Master Data Services

Since installing and setting up the entire Master Data Services package felt like overkill to get some Regex functionality, I was hoping there'd be an easy, common way out...

Comment: " I was hoping there'd be an easy, common way out" - yes CLR. .NET regular expressions support capturing groups so write the code you need and deploy it.

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's already good to know. I'm new to SQL Server (coming from Oracle) and new to .NET. I don't even know yet what "CLR" *is* aside from that it can help me use the .NET regex functionality. Hence I was wondering if there are any solutions available that I don't have to code myself. Like... plug and play. Since I'm assuming I'm not the first person that needs this functionality.

Comment: @Wouter to learn more about working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series I am writing on SQL Server Central on this topic: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (FYI: free registration is required to read content on that site, but it's worth it :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a CLR implementation that is super easy to install, and includes Regex capturing group functions.

http://www.sqlsharp.com/

I have installed this in a separate database called 'SQL#' (simply by using the provided installation .sql script), and the functions are located inside a schema with the same name. As a result I can use the function as follows:

```
select SQL#.SQL#.RegEx_CaptureGroup( 'test (2005) test', '\((20[012][0-9]|19[5-9][0-9])\)', 1, NULL, 1, -1, '');
```

Would be nice if this was included by default in SQL Server...

Comment: Hello. I'm the creator of [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) and wanted to mention a few things: 1) I recently released v 4.0 which includes many performance enhancements, including **RegEx_CaptureGroup**, 2) there is now a **RegEx_CaptureGroupCapture** function to get a specific repeat of a specific group, 3) Full version (i.e. not free) includes TVFs **RegEx_CaptureGroups** and **RegEx_CaptureGroupCaptures** to get all instances within a string, and 4) when working with <= 4k characters, use the 4k versions of RegEx and String functions for much better performance: **RegEx_CaptureGroup4k**